# Does there exist a nonzero vector that's orthogonal to 4 linearly independent vectors in $\mathbb{R}^{4}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, orthogonality

I am preparing for a linear algebra exam and there is a multiple choice part, where you have to answer yes or no.

The question I am wondering about is the following:

You are given 4 4-dimensional linearly independent non-zero vectors. Does there exist a vector $v \in \mathbb{R}^4 \setminus\lbrace 0 \rbrace$ that is orthogonal to each of your given vectors.

My guess is "no", since we are in $\mathbb{R}^4$ and the vectors are linearly independent. If the given vectors are orthogonal to one another, there is simply no direction left for $v$ in order to be orthogonal to each of them, but I am unsure, if I am missing something in the case that the given vectors are not orthogonal.

I try to prove the statement with the rank-nullity theorem:

Suppose the 4 given vectors are $w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4$. I define the matrix $W=\begin{pmatrix} w_1^T \\ w_2^T \\ w_3^T \\ w_4^T \end{pmatrix}$. The rank of the matrix $W$ is 4 and the dimension of the space spaned by $w_1, w_2, w_3, w_4$ is 4 as well since the vectors are linearly independent. Hence by the rank nullity theorem the dimension of the kernel of $W$ is $0$. Therefore, the nullvector is the only vector $v$ that satisfies $Wv=0$, which equals to the vector $v$ being orthogonal to $w_1, \dots, w_4$. Since $v$ is supposed to be a non-zero vector, the statement is wrong.

Can someone please check, if this is correct?

Comment: Don't forget that **the zero vector** is also a vector!

Comment: @Joe but not if they are linearly independent right?

Comment: @HansLundmark Thank you, I forgot to include, that the 0 vector is taken out of the consideration

Comment: @samabu: OK, in that case you're right.

Comment: To prepare for your exam, I recommend trying to prove questions like this. If your four vectors are linearly independent, they span the space. So assume there is a nonzero vector orthogonal to all four, and derive a contradiction.

Comment: Your solution looks perfect to me.  An alternative is to note that if $v$ is orthogonal to $4$ linearly independent vectors, then it is also orthogonal to itself (as the $4$ vectors form a basis), so $|v|=0$ and $v=0$.  This type of reasoning is often useful, so it is good to have this up your sleeve as well, but your solution is fine too.

Comment: @Joe, yes you are right thanks!